# Amplitudes and phases of transform of an image

Tags: molecules, symmetry

I have recorded an image of a large macromolecule and after several types of image analysis, have obtained a rotationally averaged image, that is not quite perfect, but appears to show 6-fold symmetry. With the origin on the axis of rotation, I compute a transform and unlike most of my colleagues, if I actually look at the amplitudes and phases of the transform. I have only one image of this molecule and no more specimen left. So my questions are:

1. What feature(s) I should see in the transform’s amplitudes and phases?
2. If the amplitudes and phases do not conform exactly to my expectations, what would that mean?
3. What are the factors that degrade my image?
4. What should I do to make the transform conform to my expectations?

Any ideas are welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you describe more about the chemistry behind your data? What technique did you use to acquire data?  X-rays or something? I haven't been around a long time, but I don't think chem.se gets referred many questions from photo.se.